# Proving Complex Inequality relation

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

The problem is:

Let $f: \mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function defined on $\mathbb{D}$. Suppose $|f(z)| \leq 1 $ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that for any integer $n \geq 1  $ and any $z \in \mathbb{D}$ we have: $|f^{(n)}(z)| \leq n!(1 - |z|)^{-n}$.

My attempt:
z belongs to $\mathbb{D}$ which is open, so there exists an $r >0$ such that $D(z,r) \subset \mathbb{D} $.

Then by Cauchy's inequality:

$$|f^{(n)}(z)| \leq \frac{n!}{r^n}sup|f|_{\partial D(z, r)}\leq \frac{n!}{r^n}$$

and $|z| < r < 1$, then $ (\frac{1}{1 - |z|})^n > 1$

or $(1 - |z|)^{-n} > 1$

But how can I relate this to r and therefore replace in the inequality?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How large can $r$ be so that $D(z,r) \subset \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: not larger than 1 no?

Comment: That's true, but you can do better. The bound depends on $z$ of course.

Comment: $r < 1 - |z|$ but this gives $1/r^n > 1/(1 - |z|)^n$ when I need it to be less not greater...

Comment: But the inequality $\lvert f^{(n)}(z)\rvert \leqslant n!\cdot r^{-n}$ holds for _every_ $r \in \bigl(0, 1-\lvert z\rvert\bigr)$, so …

Comment: I understand but concluding that $|f^{(n)} (z)| \leq n!(1 - |z|)^{-n}$ would not be true because 1 - |z| is the greatest value of r and we're dividing by r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything but the final step. As you stated, the Cauchy inequalities yield

$$\lvert f^{(n)}(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!}{r^n}\tag{1}$$

for every $r > 0$ such that $D(z,r) \subset \mathbb{D}$. Hence we can replace the right hand side of $(1)$ with the infimum over all admissible $r$, i.e.

$$\lvert f^{(n)}(z)\rvert \leqslant \inf\: \biggl\{\frac{n!}{r^n} : 0 < r < 1 - \lvert z\rvert\biggr\} = \frac{n!}{(1-\lvert z\rvert)^n}. \tag{2}$$

Comment: I see, I was complicating things, thank you